# Why does a task spawned with `task::spawn` not get executed when it's inside of a loop, inside another blocking task?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio

I'm studying Rust and I encountered a scenario which I can't explain. I have a blocking operation (listening on a network interface for packets) which I'm offloading to another thread. Everything works fine then, but I have another set of operations I need to do on those packets, and for this I figured I'd spawn another thread/task and have it handle those.

What I found out is that this second thread/task never gets started, and I can't pin-point why.

The code is running with Tokio, so my main function is annotated with `#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread", worker_threads = 10)]`. Inside of it comes this (I've tried to isolate the problem to this simplest form):

```
task::spawn_blocking(move || {
    println!("Spawned blocking!"); // This is executed correctly

    loop { // Inside this loop I wait for a .next() packet
        println!("PRE SPAWN"); // This executes fine, and repeatedly, as expected.
        tokio::spawn(async move { 
            // This block is supposed to process the packet in a way that 
            // doesn't block the waiting for next packets.
            println!("Spawned INSIDE blocking!"); // Never gets called
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre], your code works as expected on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=69dc2113642e26dd08457bc630610352)

Comment: @cafce25 interestingly, your playground works exactly as I expect. When I remove the `.await`, it behaves like I reported. Still not quite clear how the task is run anyway but if I await on it the `spawn` inside of it starts to be executed...

In my case, I start the `spawn_blocking` code and proceed to do more stuff afterward, I wouldn't like to keep `await`-ing.

Comment: In summary, I think that now what I'm wondering is: why does awaiting/not-awaiting a parent (blocking) task influence whether a task spawned inside of it runs or not (`[...] INSIDE blocking!`), while has _no effect_ on the code directly inside that blocking task (`PRE SPAWN`)?

Comment: Maybe this part of the [docs](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) is relevant "This function is intended for non-async operations that eventually finish on their own. If you want to spawn an ordinary thread, you should use thread::spawn instead."

Comment: I think without the `await` since the main thread exits the runtime is being shut down, but killing blocking threads isn't part of the shutdown procedure, but that is mostly guesswork.

Comment: That makes total sense! D'oh! Thanks a lot. I'll try to confirm that!

Comment: Ah should have read on the very next sentence explains it and confirms my suspicion "Closures spawned using spawn_blocking cannot be cancelled abruptly; there is no standard low level API to cause a thread to stop running."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see the behaviour you get probably because you don't `await` the future in question and don't do any other sleeping or work there either so it ends resulting in the runtime shutting down. Once that procedure started no new tasks are being scheduled hence no `Spawned INSIDE blocking!`. But the [thread spawning these](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html)

> cannot be cancelled abruptly; there is no standard low level API to cause a thread to stop running.

the docs further state

> When you shut down the executor, it will wait indefinitely for all blocking operations to finish. You can use shutdown_timeout to stop waiting for them after a certain timeout.

So the blocking task keeps on running and printing `PRE SPAWN`.